# Export SPSS results with Syntax

Tags: syntax, export, spss

I have been working until now with SAS. In SAS there is the option to creat an word or pdf Output with the ods command.
This is what I am also looking for SPSS. I can calculate linear Regression Model with Snytax. But i cant find a command for export the result to word or pdf. Is the possible in SPSS? So far, I only export via the menu. But i want it full automatic.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMS can capture and export output in a wide variety of formats.  Also OUTPUT EXPORT can export objects from the Viewer